# Can't query more than 30 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT
CONVERT_TZ(date1, '+0:00', '-7:00') as date,
sum(base_subtotal) as `base_subtotal`
FROM sales
WHERE date1 > (NOW() - interval 90 DAY)
GROUP BY DAY(date)
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Despite pulling 90 days of data, MySQL is only returning the 30 day tail for any particular date interval. So, if today is June 11, and I pull the request with a `"interval 30 day"` command, I will get all dates between now and 30 days ago. However, if I do the same with a 60 day command I get the dates for 30 days ago STARTING at a month ago, in other words I get dates between April 14 and May 11, but oddly enough also May 31.

The sum totals per day also start getting larger, and when I run the code for just a specific month to validate the totals, say I use the command `"HERE Date(date1) BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31'"` I get different values.

What am I doing wrong? I read something about "overflow" errors in Java, but not sure this is what's happening. I just want to see the total number of sales per day for the last 90 days.

Comment: Try to reduce your problem to [MCVE]. Often by doing that, you'll figure out the issue yourself.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day  to get totals for each date, `GROUP BY DATE(CONVERT_TZ(date1, '+0:00', '-7:00'))`

Comment: What Barmar said; but to elaborate, you are not just getting the "30 day tail", you are getting the total for each day of the month (1-31) for those 90 days, and an effectively random selection of "date" values that had that day of the month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem can be seen at this line:

```
GROUP BY DAY(date)
```

since day cannot be smaller than 1 or bigger than 31 and it will be the same, you will need to group by date instead if you want to get more results.

Answer (score 4):

`DAY(date)` is just the day of the month. So when you group by this, results from the same day in different months will be grouped together. You should use `GROUP BY DATE(date)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your group by is doing it for only the day of the month (ie. 1st, 2nd, 3rd... 31st) and grouping those together.  If you change "group by day(date)" to "group by date", it should work.